# foo({0, 0}): Is this using initializer lists?

Tags: c++, c++11, syntax, initializer-list

How does this code allow calling foo without naming the Vec type at the construction site? Is this syntax a case of C++11 initializer lists?

```
struct Vec {
    Vec(int x, int y) {
    }
};
void foo(Vec) {
}
int main() {
    foo({0, 0}); // normally I'd pass Vec(0, 0) or Vec{0, 0}
}
```

I'm sure this is a duplicate question but I don't know what to search for.

Comment: it is called *copy-list-initialization syntax*

Answer (score 4):

As stated by Piotr S., this is [copy list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization#copy-list-initialization). The *braced-init-list* is used to initialize the function parameter. In copy-list-initialization, only non-explicit constructors are considered. This means that if `Vec::Vec(int, int)` was explicit, `{0, 0}` would cause a compiler error and `Vec{0, 0}` would be required.

Comment: Thanks. Is copy list initialization a feature new in C++11?